# What does "möbius" (moebius) mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In [Starcraft II](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StarCraft_II:_Wings_of_Liberty) there was a mission called [The Moebius Factor](http://starcraft.wikia.com/wiki/The_Moebius_Factor). Unrelated to that, a new [Futurama](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futurama) episode called [Möbius Dick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_Dick_%28Futurama%29) was recently released.

Does anyone have any idea what does the word mean? Either generally, or in connection with any of the aforementioned phrases.

Comment: Moebius is also a pseudonym of the french comic artist Jean Giraud, who did the famous *Incal* series of SF comics. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_Giraud

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This refers to the 2D-3D crossover object known as a [Möbius strip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_strip). From Wikipedia:

> The Möbius strip or Möbius band (pronounced UK: /ˈmɜːbiəs/ or US: /ˈmoʊbiəs/ in English, [ˈmøːbi̯ʊs] in German) (alternatively written Mobius or Moebius in English) is a surface with only one side and only one boundary component. The Möbius strip has the mathematical property of being non-orientable. It can be realized as a ruled surface. It was discovered independently by the German mathematicians August Ferdinand Möbius and Johann Benedict Listing in 1858.

[image]

Comment: I bet not even you would be able to define what you meant with '2D-3D crossover' (*apart denoting that it is a surface*; it certainly does not point to the fact that the object has only one side and I feel it is only a metaphor for 'beware: this is complex').

Comment: The 2D-3D crossover, I believe it could be explained, relates to the making use of this shape in topological space, where it is both a 2-dimensional manifold, yet seen as / spliced into, or can be interpreted (through thought experiments, and whatnot) as 3-dimensional. It also has the interesting property of not being simply connected, but seeming so.

Comment: @Unreason: Yes, I use metaphors.

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment - you are right, my beef however is that *any* surface is a two-dimensional topological manifold and I feel that this metaphor does not really help someone who has no knowledge of geometry (nor it would be appreciated by someone who know geometry). Still, I am making too much noise over this - the definition given after the introduction is well chosen.

Comment: @Unreason: I meant the introduction to be breezy and light, using "crossover" as one might to describe a musician who crosses genres to appeal to different audiences. I really never imagined anybody would try to carry the figure of speech out to six decimal places. If your math professor said the same thing to introduce the topic it would be intended to draw a laugh, and it probably would.

Comment: This is topology, not geometry.

Comment: @BlueRaja, well, yes, I agree, in a certain sense, but also eventually, definitely, don't agree in a different sense. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometry#Topology_and_geometry ; there is semantical overlap and if trying to write something for audience that knows not of Moebius maybe it is better to use the term *geometry*.

Comment: Sorry, still confusing to me... in what sense is this a "2D-3D crossover object", and what does that mean? I'm trying really hard to understand what this means, even metaphorically, and it's not clear... if you consider just the plain strip/band (without the twist), then it also seems to satisfy the vaguely defined criteria of being a "2D-3D crossover object": it's a surface (a 2-dimensional manifold), and is embedded in 3D space. So since I presume you meant to refer to some feature of the Mobius strip that is not shared by the simple strip/band, it's not clear what that is. :-(

Comment: @Shree: I used *crossover object* as a metaphor. Not to be taken literally. Although it does cross over.

Comment: @Robusto初夢: Yes, but I don't understand the metaphor either! In what way is the "metaphor" *2D-3D crossover object* more applicable to the Möbius strip than to the normal band? Every crossover between 2D and 3D that's present in one is also present in the other, right?

Answer (score 12):

The Futurama episode is a pun, combining [Moby Dick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moby-Dick) (the famous white whale) with the mathematician [August Möbius](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/August_Ferdinand_M%C3%B6bius).  The episode is about killing a space-whale, and Futurama episode-names are [often geeky puns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Futurama_episodes#Season_1_.281999.29).

Möbius is by far most famous for his [Möbius strip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_strip), a three-dimensional surface with only one side, and a popular cultural reference *(in the States, at least, children are taught about Möbius strips in elementary school)*.  However, that's not the only thing he's known for - for instance, in college-level mathematics, the [Möbius function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function) is very important in the study of the [Riemann-Zeta function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/540/what-is-the-riemann-zeta-function).

---

The Starcraft mission is referring to the [Möebius Foundation](http://starcraft.wikia.com/wiki/M%C3%B6ebius_Foundation), a fictional organization which plays an important role in the game's storyline.  It actually has nothing to do with Möbius, other than likely being named after him simply because game-developers are often math geeks :P

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why @Thursagen deleted his answer, but it did contain the only non-trivial information relevant to OP's question (defining a [Möbius strip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_strip) seems trivial to me, since however you spell *mobius*, Google's top result will probably be that Wikipedia page).

**Möbius Dick** is simply a pun on [Moby Dick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moby-Dick) (or, *The Whale*, by Herman Melville).

In passing I'll just mention that *Moby Dick* has long been fertile ground for puns based on the slang usage of *dick* for *penis*, the fact that a common type of whale is the *sperm whale*, and that as an "unknown adjective", *moby* suggests something mouldy, moribund, or otherwise unsavoury. In this case the Futurama writers seem to have avoided those connotations.